# How to apply skinning on PrimeFaces Component(ToolTip)

Tags: primefaces

I am using Prime Faces tool tip. I want to know can i change the look and feel of the prime Faces tooltip by applying css or skinning. Like make bigger box and change the color and font of the Tooltip etc.

I am using Prime Faces 2.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the style by adding `CSS` to `style` or `styleClass` attributes.

Also, **I strongly recommend to upgrade to 3.0.M4 or 3.0.RC1-Snapshot!**

EDIT:

I've found this piece, regarding tooltips styling: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/prime-showcase/src/main/webapp/ui/tooltipStyling.xhtml?r=1434

As you can see there, you can apply some styling by using some css classes.

Also this is the migration guide for 3.0.M4(RC1): http://wiki.primefaces.org/display/General/Migration+Guide+to+3.0

Comment: Actually i am using Prime Faces 2.2. Is Prime Faces 3 is fully compatible with Prime Faces 2.2. I mean to say that if i remove the jar file of Prime Faces 2.2 and include the jar file of Prime Faces 3.0, then everything will work fine or i will have to made some changes to my Prime Faces 2.2 code? Also it is not working <p:tooltip global="true" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide"
           style="margin: 8px; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid blue; background-color: yellow; position: absolute; z-index: 2;"/>   No yellow back ground color or nothing happen after applying style, why ?

Comment: Thanks. But what do you mean by **you can apply some styling by using some css classes**?Do you want to say that only those  attributes that is defined in the code ?  In the toolTip there is only style attrubute, no styleClass attribute.

Comment: @Basit Have you accessed the link I gave you? You will see there what do I mean... also there is a styleClass attribute for the version 3 :)

Comment: Yes i have seen the code :) that's why I said **those attributes that is defined in the code** . Here code means the attributes that is define in the code on the link that you have given to me. Like in the code there is _width_, _padding_, _background_, _color_, _textAlign_, _border_, _tip_, _name_ attributes are present. So i want to ask that can i use only these attributes in my style attribute? If i use other attributes then those attributes won't create any difference but these attributes can override? Is it ?

Comment: @Basit I think and it's normal to be allowed to use any css attribute

Comment: @sapuny No, it isn't working....May be it work on Prime Faces 3.0. I also read the Prime Faces 2.2 guide, inside the guide whenever skinning portions was appear, it was mentioned that read the skinning section, but i didn't find any section. Yes on webpage showcase and inside the guide skinning applied to charts... If i find any solution then i will post it here. Thanks :) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you can also go the way of overriding certain CSS properties by using style definitions with higher precedence in your general CSS file. I described this in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13610162/840977). Colors, borders and paddings are no problem, however, the position is rather tricky as PrimeFaces places the tooltips as divs outside the normal structure and the apparently uses some computed absolute positioning to place them.