# Apply theme for some Primefaces components

Tags: primefaces

I want to disable theme style for some Primefaces components. I tried this configuration:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But I can't find any solution. Can you propose some alternative?

Comment: That's for disabling themes for the whole application..

Comment: I agree. How I can disable theme for several components?

Comment: You mean disabling by type of component or just a random ones by id? You'll need to override the Primefaces' CSS.

Comment: Well, I want to use calendar with default theme but on the same page I want to disable input filed theme.

Comment: Basically, it's what is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734478/how-to-apply-primefaces-skinning-on-only-one-component-on-page-leaving-otheres-u